# How to perform list comprehension on the following two lists?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

This question has probably been asked here before but me being new to python and lack of better keywords to search led me to ask the question.

I have two lists:

```
list1 = ['John', 'Don', 'Sam']
list2 = ['Melissa', 'Amber', 'Liz']
couples = [x + ' and ' y for x in list1 y in list2] # I can't do that
```

My couples list should look like this:

```
['John and Melissa', 'Don and Amber', 'Sam and Liz']
```

How do I concatenate this two lists that way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I iterate through two lists in parallel in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-can-i-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> list1 = ['John', 'Don', 'Sam']
>>> list2 = ['Melissa', 'Amber', 'Liz']
>>> [' and '.join(i) for i in zip(list1, list2)]
['John and Melissa', 'Don and Amber', 'Sam and Liz']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip()` to iterate through both lists:

```
couples = [x + ' and ' + y for x, y in zip(list1, list2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

`zip` both lists and use `str.format`

```
list1 = ['John', 'Don', 'Sam']
list2 = ['Melissa', 'Amber', 'Liz']
print ["{} and {}".format(*name) for name in zip(list1,list2)]
['John and Melissa', 'Don and Amber', 'Sam and Liz']
```

You can also use enumerate:

```
list1 = ['John', 'Don', 'Sam']
list2 = ['Melissa', 'Amber', 'Liz']
print ["{} and {}".format(name,list2[ind]) for ind, name in enumerate(list1)]
['John and Melissa', 'Don and Amber', 'Sam and Liz']
```